# multiple minimax solutions in zero-sum games

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

recently learned the minimax theorem for zero-sum games, and had a clarification on it. The minimax solution gives the value for the game V, and is also a Nash Equilibria.

So, does that mean that all Nash EQ in zero-sum games have the same value V, and they are all minimax solutions? If so, I'm not able to come up with a example of a zero-sum game with multiple Nash Equilibria (besides a trivial one where each player has multiple identical actions). Would someone be able to provide an example as well? Thanks!